# Acoustic permeability of polypropylene

Tags: waves, acoustics, material-science

I've searched the web for the coefficient of acoustic permeability of polypropylene but couldn't find any.

I have a situation where there's a $3.3(mm)$ thick polypropylene layer over my target, and I'm beaming acoustic wave at the target to somehow actuate it. I want to know how much intensity of the sound, assuming the sound intensity profile between source and target is uniform and undiminishing, gets through the barrier and hits the target.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the acoustic attenuation coefficient.
The value depends on the frequency of the sound. In general increases with frequency.

Here is a table that includes two types of polypropylene, at a frequency of 5 MHz:
https://www.ndt.net/links/proper.htm

Before you can estimate the effect of attenuation for your project you need to know the frequency of the sound used.

Latter addition

You may try to find the attenuation at 50 Hz but it may be easier (and more accurate) to just measure it. 
There are several ways to define the attenuation coefficient, using either intensities in SI units or in decibels. Assuming you find a value for your application in literature, you use it according to the definition in the paper. Usually is given for unit distance so you have to multiply by actual thickness of your material.

And you may want to look at the impedance mismatch at the interfaces. This may have a larger effect on the intensity loss than the attenuation in the medium.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I've looked into attenuation, and surely it's what I need. My working frequency is 50Hz, so I'll love if you can help with that. Also doesn't the depth/thickness of the material factor in, a research paper I looked at said the energy loss by a pressure wave is proportional to thickness of the material (increase viscosity). It also says lower frequencies are affected more than higher ones. It gives the relation $f_1d=constant$ $f_1$: frequency; $d$: thickness. https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/engineering/sound-absorption-coefficient

Comment: And also, provided the attenuation coefficient $x$, how's the loss calculated in terms of intensity loss?

Comment: See the additions to the answer.

Comment: Well, it seem difficult to find attenuation for 50Hz sound wave, thus I couldn't find any, and I don't have the facility to do a practical measure. I'll settle for any alternative to know exactly how much loss I'll have (estimate or not). All I need is the percentage loss in intensity of a 50Hz directional sound wave beamed through a 3.3mm white polypropylene sheet. I'll be glad if you can help.

Comment: I don't see how would one go about finding "exactly" how much loss you have in your material. For one thing, you did not exactly define it. Just saying "polypropylene" is not enough. Polymer fibers may be mixed with various fillers and additives and this will change their properties. Is your material a composite of polypropylene? Do you know its porosity? Also, I am curious how do you get a directional beam of 50 Hz sound waves. How big is your sound source? The wavelength in air is about 6-7 meters.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that much information about the material, but it's not composite at least. The directional in this context isn't the ultrasound kind used on US warships. This is a wave created by multiple transducers converging at the target, this increases the directivity of sound generated at high frequency. This is my first time bringing theoretical acoustic into the real world, so please bear with my inexperience. So a 50Hz sound wave requires how large source?